# Java compiler doesn't see sibling packages

Tags: java, compiler-errors, package

[image]From Windows command line, I am trying to compile a java file in package com.example.web that imports a class from package com.example.model but keep getting the message that the package com.example.model does not exist.

From what I can tell, the compiler doesn't recognize sibling packages for some reason, as I do not get the error message when I try to import the package com.example but I do get it if I try to import com.example.test. I've compiled the files in the other packages that are not dependent on imports without an issue from the same directory. I'm almost positive that I've had access to sibling packages from the command line in the past.

```
package com.example.web;

import com.example.*;
import com.example.test.*;
import com.example.model.*;

public class Test{
}
```

I get 2 errors saying that package com.example.model and com.example.test do not exist. They're in my file structure, they have .class files in them.

UPDATE: It works if I add com.example.model and com.example.test to my classpath, but I was under the impression this was unnecessary if the dependencies shared the same parent folder as the class I was compiling. Am I mistaken? Did this use to be the case but changed in the last few years? It's been awhile since I've compiled directly from command line, but I don't remember having to do this before.

Comment: Probably something wrong with your project structure or the way you're compiling. Would need to see what it looks like.

Comment: There's no reason this shouldn't work as-is (delta paths with spaces in them are something I *never* do under Windows).